# Setting mylti-byte characters in to message body in Java

Tags: jakarta-mail

**Context:**
We have a requirement of appending some text to the body of a mail message received in an exchange server. For this purpose we are using Java Mail API to read the mail, append the text and set it to bodypart and write it as .eml file.

When we read the mail and save it to file without any modifications, the original message and characters are intact and shows up fine in the .eml file.
However when we append the text to body and write it, some characters do not appear. They appear as '?' characters in .eml file.

**Here is a sample text which is coming from mail:**

專案價格申請 (申請編號：SQ-3303112，終端用戶：桃園國際機場股份有限公司，經銷商：華電聯網股份有限公司) 已經由代理商 (精技電腦股份有限公司) 代為重新提交通知

**After appending the custom text to the body the output looks like this**

?案?格申? (申???：SQ-3303112，?端用?：桃?????股份有限公司，??商：????股份有限公司) 已?由代理商 (精技??股份有限公司) 代?重新提交通知

```
public void parseMultipart(Multipart mPart) throws Exception {
    // Parse the Multipart to find the body
    // Loop through all of the BodyPart's
    for (int i = 0; i < mPart.getCount(); i++) {
        // Grab the body part
        BodyPart bp = mPart.getBodyPart(i);
        // Grab the disposition for attachments
        String disposition = bp.getDisposition();

        // It's not an attachment
        if (disposition == null && bp instanceof MimeBodyPart) {
            MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) bp;

            // Check to see if we're in the screwy situation where
            // the message text is buried in another Multipart
            if (mbp.getContent() instanceof Multipart) {
                // Use recursion to parse the sub-Multipart
                parseMultipart((Multipart) mbp.getContent());
            } else {
                // Time to grab and edit the body
                if (mbp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                        ........
                    
                } else if (mbp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                    // Grab the body containing the HTML version
                    String body =  (String)mbp.getContent();
                    StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder(body);
                    // Add our custom message to the HTML 
                    bf.append("<html><head></head><body>[APPLICATION_ID=123456]</body></html>");
                    mbp.setContent(bf.toString(), mbp.getContentType());
                    _msg.saveChanges();
                    mbp.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", mbp.getEncoding());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried so many things like setting the encoding type to UTF-8, base64 etc. nothing seems to work. Any pointers?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem.  Can you contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com?  I'd like to get a sample message that shows this problem.  Also, what version of JavaMail are you using?  If you're using an older version, try with the current [1.5.2 version](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.2_Release).

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for the response> I have sent the code and the email sample to the javamail_ww@oracle.com

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't gotten your message.  Perhaps it was trapped by some spam filter?  Can you resend as a plain text message?

Comment: Offline discussion determined that the message was most likely incorrectly encoded, which is what caused the problem described here.